# Your Favorite Sound to create 

Tags: sound-effects, foley

What is your Favorite sound you have created? How did you create it and where did you use  it?

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was the sound for a blob that gives birth to a kind of planet, to hard to explain lol http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ig01-wSIxUY

[youtube]Ig01-wSIxUY[/youtube]

starts at 0:22s

Used lemons, eggs, a jar of marmalade, and a couple of synths
Used pitch shifting and a bit of maxxBass

Comment: Nice work, cool short.

Comment: Beautiful work!

Comment: Wow, very nice.  I want to see (and hear) more.

Comment: Fantastic short, must have been a great project to work on! And you did a great job on the sound design! 

Comment: Beautyful !  and sound work is clear and nothin is standing out..
How long do u working to make such thing?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words Pretaeperon! It was done over a period of one month, its hard to estimate how much time it was put on the project, i'll say around 10 days, as i was doing a lot of field recording to help out some friends and doing foley for a picture and for a another short animation.
I've checked your myspace, cool stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

I robbed the end piece of a metal shelving unit from a skip at University. Got some great stuff out of it that still has a place of pride in my library. It was shaken and hit and dropped. Large bendy piece of metal + endless reverb rocks!

Used many times over the years in a couple of short films. Used it last year in a show called Hero:108 and my wife sometimes nicks it for her composition work.

Answer (score 1):

Three years ago I worked on post of a doc series about climbing through Anctartica. The camera operator waited for hours to record some images of a fracture of the Perito Moreno glacier. Just when he was leaving empty-handed a great fracture happend and he could record a great shot. The members of the team were so excited at the moment that they couldn´t control themshelves from clapping their hands and shouting to congratulate the cameraman for the great work.

After editing this shot was part of a very quiet sequence and director proposed to remove the reaction of the team from the original soundrack. So we started from scratch to recreate a believable fracture using creakings of branches, snow avalanches sounds, down-pitched splashes and a large amount of ambiance layers. The sound we got was very similar to the original.